# Login Script Overview

Tags: mapping, login-script

Working on a project for an experiential learning class and well... I got asked to take care of the logon script, we're not ready to fully implement it yet, and I myself am a novice with scripts, but I tried and this is what I have. I am wondering if someone that is knowledgeable could take a look over and point out any mistakes-I can do more research as to why its wrong if I know what to look for.

Thanks for any help.

The goal of this script is to detect which group the user is a part of and then give the proper shares for the department. Payroll will have access to every department's "Payroll" share.

```
Department Key: HR, Accounting=ACT, Payroll=PYR, IT, Admin=AD, Production=PRD, Custodial=CST



Const ACT_GROUP = "cn=Accounting"
Const AD_GROUP = "cn=Admin"
Const CST_GROUP = "cn=Custodial"
Const HR_GROUP = "cn=Human Resources"
Const IT_GROUP = "cn=IT"
Const PYR_GROUP = "cn=Payroll"
Const PRD_GROUP = "cn=Production"



Set wshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")


Set ADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set CurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" &
ADSysInfo.UserName)
strGroups = LCase(Join(CurrentUser.MemberOf))

If InStr(strGroups, ACT_GROUP) Then

wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "N:",
"\\FileServer\Accounting\Department\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:",
"\\FileServer\Accounting\Users\" & wshNetwork.UserName
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "O:",
"\\FileServer\Accounting\ACTPayroll\"

ElseIf InStr(strGroups, AD_GROUP) Then

wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "N:",
"\\FileServer\Admin\Department\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:",
"\\FileServer\Admin\Users\" & wshNetwork.UserName
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "O:",
"\\FileServer\Admin\ADPayroll\"

ElseIf InStr(strGroups, CST_GROUP) Then

wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "N:",
"\\FileServer\Custodial\Department\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:",
"\\FileServer\Custodial\Users\" & wshNetwork.UserName
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "O:",
"\\FileServer\Custodial\CSTPayroll\"

ElseIf InStr(strGroups, HR_GROUP) Then

wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "g:",
"\\FileServer\Human Resources\Department\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:",
"\\FileServer\Human Resources\Users\" & wshNetwork.UserName
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "O:",
"\\FileServer\Human Resources\HRPayroll\"

ElseIf InStr(strGroups, IT_GROUP) Then

wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "g:",
"\\FileServer\IT\Department\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:",
"\\FileServer\IT\Users\" & wshNetwork.UserName
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "O:",
"\\FileServer\IT\ITPayroll\"

ElseIf InStr(strGroups, PYR_GROUP) Then

wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "g:",
"\\FileServer\Payroll\Department\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:",
"\\FileServer\Payroll\Users\" & wshNetwork.UserName
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "O:",
"\\FileServer\Payroll\PYRPayroll\"

wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Q:",
"\\FileServer\Accounting\ACTPayroll\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "R:",
"\\FileServer\Admin\ADPayroll\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "S:",
"\\FileServer\Custodial\CSTPayroll\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "T:",
"\\FileServer\Human Resources\HRPayroll\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "U:",
"\\FileServer\IT\ITPayroll\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "V:",
"\\FileServer\Production\PRDPayroll\"

ElseIf InStr(strGroups, PRD_GROUP) Then

wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "g:",
"\\FileServer\Production\Department\"
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:",
"\\FileServer\Production\Users\" & wshNetwork.UserName
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "O:",
"\\FileServer\Production\PRDPayroll\"

End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be done with a logon script? If using Group Policy Preferences is an option it is probably preferred. This way you can do it with a nice GUI and target it to groups the same way. Also it maps name to GUID so if a group name changes it will still work (not so much in a script unless you remember to change the name there also). Additionally you have the ability to see possible errors that occur in a workstation's Event Logs when this processes during logon. This gives a nice overview: [Using Group Policy Preferences to Map Drives Based on Group Membership](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership.aspx)

If you need it to be a script, does nested group membership matter? Perhaps check http://www.rlmueller.net/freecode2.htm for some good sample scripts.